# DAX calculate previous value also when it doesn't exist

Tags: dax, calculated-columns, powerpivot

I have data that collects "snapshots" of a Warehouse.
It has three columns:
*SnapshotDate*, *Item*, *OnHand*

(Real data has nearly 100.000 records for each *SnapshotDate*, here I post an example)

[image]

I want to measure the ***Delta OnHand*** with respect to the previuos Date (whatever it is).

So I've set three calculated columns:

**PreviousDate**

```
=
var currentDate = Inventory[SnapshotDate]
return CALCULATE( MAX( Inventory[SnapshotDate]); 
FILTER( ALL(Inventory); Inventory[SnapshotDate] < currentDate)
)
```

**PreviousOnHand**

```
= LOOKUPVALUE(Inventory[OnHand]; Inventory[SnapshotDate]; Inventory[PreviousDate]; Inventory[Item]; Inventory[Item])+0
```

**OnHandDelta**

```
=Inventory[OnHand]-Inventory[PreviuosOnHand]
```

**Delta measure:**

```
Delta:=SUM(Inventory[OnHandDelta])
```

When I pivot this data, I'd like to see 0 (red bordered cell) when the data doesn't exist and more important I should see the Delta value -10 (cyan cell).

[image]

How could this be achieved?

[Link to the test Excel file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=153EO_VU-PhekFzSuE6W6iwH2-xMJEfiW)

Comment: Have you tried adding +0 to your PreviousOnHand measure and setting a new measure for your current OnHandValue which also has +0? Use the new OnHandValue measure in your other measures.

Comment: The hint of +0 for PreviousOnHand calculated columns is preciuos (instead of my IF solution). Instead I don't understand when you say "setting a new measure for your current OnHandValue which also has +0". I have added a link to the Excel file to my post.

Comment: You are directly referencing the Onhand values in your table. Create a New measure CurrentOnHandValue = Sum(Inventory[Onhand])+0 and use CurrentOnHandValue where you have used Inventory[OnHand].

Comment: I have created the measure CurrentOnHandValue = Sum(Inventory[Onhand])+0.
However I can use this measure only in the calculated column "OnHandDelta".
(nothing changes in the pivot).
In the calc. column "PreviousOnHand" I can't use it inside the LOOKUP function.

Comment: Can you add a new measure =CurrentOnHandValue-Sum(Inventory[PreviousOnHand]) and show that in the pivot table? Also include the CurrentOnHandValue on the pivot table.

Comment: (Screenshot new pivot: [CurrentOnhandValue](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mHzF7R8VUpuKR9HKehGR4YueNGAtZDkw)
I have added the measure but nothing has changed, please take a look to the Excel file if you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that combination of date / item (15/04/2019, Item C) simply does not exist in your fact table. So it makes no difference what measure you create, it will never be calculated.

One approach is to create separate dimension tables for Date and Item, loaded to data model, with relationships to your fact table.

Query **Date Dimension**:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Grouped = Table.Sort(Table.Group(Source, {"SnapshotDate"}, {}), "SnapshotDate"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Grouped",{{"SnapshotDate", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Query **Item Dimension**:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Grouped = Table.Sort(Table.Group(Source, {"Item"}, {}), "Item"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Grouped",{{"Item", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

Now you can create what you want as MEASURES, with no calculated columns needed:

Measure **On Hand Current**:

```
On Hand Current:= 
    SUM ( Inventory[OnHand] ) + 0
```

Measure **On Hand Previous**:

```
On Hand Previous:=
VAR DateCurrent = 
    IF ( 
        HASONEVALUE ( 'Date Dimension'[SnapshotDate] ),
        VALUES ( 'Date Dimension'[SnapshotDate] ),
        BLANK()
    )
VAR DatePrevious = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        MAX ( 'Date Dimension'[SnapshotDate] ),
        FILTER ( 
            ALL ( 'Date Dimension' ),
            'Date Dimension'[SnapshotDate] < DateCurrent
        )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        [On Hand Current], 
        FILTER ( 
            ALL ( 'Date Dimension'[SnapshotDate] ),
            'Date Dimension'[SnapshotDate] = DatePrevious
        )
    ) + 0
```

Measure **Delta**:

```
Delta:=
    [On Hand Current] - [On Hand Previous]
```

Now using dimensions from the Dimension tables in your pivot, with the Delta measure:

[image]

Updated XLSX file: https://excel.solutions/so_55740804/

Comment: Thank you, I think it's a very good solution, the only doubt I have is from a perfomance standpoint: could it be better to have calculated columns than a measure? But for now I have a more basic question: how to create Query Dimension using Power Pivot?

Comment: Use Power Query (Get & Transform Data)

Comment: Here's some valuable reading, to understand the differences (and potential performance considerations) between calculated columns and measures: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/calculated-columns-and-measures-in-dax/

Comment: In this case, to use a Calculated Column, you'd first have to create a new table which crossjoins all Dates and Items, and then apply the calculated column. This would be processed as the model is refreshed, then stored in memory. Using a measure effectively does this at run time, but dynamically for the context being evaluated in your visualisation.

Comment: Hi @Olly, the solution is quite perfect: the only problem with this seems to be that I can't filter out Delta "zero" values. For example, if I have an item `K` with the same `OnHand` (i.e. `5`) value in the three dates, in the first Date it has a `Delta` of 5. That said, if I use the Excel "Value filter" "Greater than..." 0 the row remains always visible also when from the Columns I remove the first date (01/04/2019).

Comment: Not clear what your expected behaviour is, in this case. Did you want a blank Delta returned, if no previous date exists?

Comment: Yes, it's not very simple to explain, I have created [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55829707/pivot-table-filter-zero-values)